# JBehave + Serenity metafilter work on examples table row? how to workaround it?

Tags: java, bdd, jbehave, serenity-bdd

My tests with examples table and meta filters don't want to start.
I am using jbehave-core 4.0.4 and serenity 1.1.21

I have following scenario (simplified here but also has similar issue)

```
Meta:
@env any
@run

Scenario: Add new logo by Role (test)
Given I am on soccer home page
When I login as "<login>" with "<password>" password
Examples:
| login                                 | password |
| {{site.executive.username::property}} | {{site.executive.password::property}} |
| {{site.webmaster.username::property}} | {{site.webmaster.password::property}} |
```

And I am using following command to run the tests

```
verify -Dmetafilter=+run
```

I am using this "@run" tag for test run on local computer. But this command does not run me the above scenarios. The output is "success" but the output has:

```
Scenario: Add new logo by Role (test)
Failed to run story stories/club/ClubSetups1.story
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.PerformableTree$PerformableScenario.perform(PerformableTree.java:876)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.PerformableTree$PerformableStory.performScenarios(PerformableTree.java:804)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.PerformableTree$PerformableStory.perform(PerformableTree.java:777)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.PerformableTree.performCancellable(PerformableTree.java:409)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.PerformableTree.perform(PerformableTree.java:380)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryManager$EnqueuedStory.call(StoryManager.java:291)
    at org.jbehave.core.embedder.StoryManager$EnqueuedStory.call(StoryManager.java:265)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
12 stories excluded by filter: +run -ignore
```

The strange point is that in case I add "Meta:" column with "@run" value for each row tests are executed well. So I soppose that metafilter works on examples table even in case table does not have "Meta:" column which is wrong from my point of view.

May somebody suggest the solution because for now I don't see any except adding this "Meta:" column. But it is bad because I have to duplicate all the parameters I have.

Answer (score 0):

See if reverting to previous version of jbehave helps . There seems to be a bug with the 4.0.4 . See this link 
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/jbehave-dev/7OxwmOXZPVk